# How to check when formik is initalize and ready?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik to handle forms in my app. With useRef i am managing to call Formik props outside Formik.

```
const form = useRef(null);
const formProps = form.current;

useEffect(() => {
    getUser(props.match.params.userId)
}, []);

console.log(formProps)

<Formik
  ref={form}
  initialValues={userData}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     {props => (
          <Form>

           </Form>
      )}
</Formik>
```

From URL I am getting userId and fetching that user from server and saving it in redux store. Then that data is set as initial value of Formik. When from other view I navigate to this one with:

```
  props.history.push(`users/${userId}/update`);
```

console log writes down null, and when i refresh page i get result Formik {}. Dont know why i am getting result null, maybe cause it triggers beffore formik is ready?

Comment: do you remember finding any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is functional component, so our code is executed line by line.

Our function run as first: `const form = useRef(null);`, then `const formProps = form.current;`.
After than run `console.log(formProps)` with `form.current` which is not initialized (which is equal to `null`).
Our ref object get reference/value when function of component reach/execute lines with `<Formik/>` JSX representation.

`Console.log()` prints Formik reference values after first rerender of component (so when we change state, props or sometimes refresh page (depend on how and where is defined our component).

Comment: I know, but component renders one more cause i have redux store state as a prop of that component, so when i get user data component render one more time, and Formik shoud be initialite by that time. Do you have any advice how i can solve it?

Comment: If you use redux useSelector() hook, you should know that useSelector do not rerender your component if you try to return object from store by useSelector(). Store in redux is immutable, so returned object  from useSelector is always the same, and our component do not recognize new state (difference). By useSelector we should return only simple types, like string, number, boolean etc. (not  whole objects). When you want rerender component for returned objects from redux, we should write our own equalityFunction for useSelector: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: but something else is going on here, when i refresh page component get render three times, and on third time form is not null anymore, but when i redirect with react router props.history.push it only gets render two times, and i need that third one